# Creating a hash class constant from a hash with array keys

Tags: ruby

I have a class with a constant which is a hash:

```
  class ServiceMap
    MARKET_MAP = 
     {
       "Fords" => [11,2,43],
       "Edison" => [3,15]
     }

  end
```

I would like to generate a new constant dynamically that would look something like this:

```
CODE_MAP = {
 11: "Fords",
 2: "Fords",
 43: "Fords",
 3: "Edison",
 15: "Edison"
}
```

Until now I have this code but not able to figure out the right way of doing this and the best way to create a hash from a hash with array keys.

```
 def self.CODE_MAP
   @CODE_MAP ||= MARKET_MAP.inject({}){ do_something }
 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CODE_MAP = MARKET_MAP.reduce({}) do |memo,(k,v)|
  v.each { |x| memo[x] = k }
  memo
end
# => {
#  11: "Fords",
#  2: "Fords",
#  43: "Fords",
#  3: "Edison",
#  15: "Edison"
# }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Enumberable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object)

```
MARKET_MAP.each_with_object({}) do |(name, num_arr), hash| 
  num_arr.each { |num| hash[num] = name }
end
=> {11=>"Fords", 2=>"Fords", 43=>"Fords", 3=>"Edison", 15=>"Edison"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write:

```
Hash[MARKET_MAP.flat_map{|x,y| y.product [x] }]
```